# Cannot Resolve the Error in Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

[image: My directory structure]I am trying to retrieve particular row from the database by providing the id number of the row using console. But I am getting some kind of error which is I don't have idea whats wrong in code. I have tried a lot to resolve it, but nothing helped please help me to resolve this error. Here is my entire project code.

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate 
 Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-
configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->
    <!--Below are other values for hbm2ddl.auto validate: validate the schema, 
        makes no changes to the database. update: update the schema. create: creates 
        the schema, destroying previous data. create-drop: drop the schema at the 
        end of the session. -->
    <!--property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mujju</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my hibernate.hbm.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-mapping>  
 <class name="com.Beans.Employee" table="employee">  
<id name="Id">  
 <generator class="increment"></generator>  
</id>  

<property name="F_Name"></property>  
<property name="L_Name"></property>  
 <many-to-one name="com.Beans.Employee"></many-to-one>
</class>  

</hibernate-mapping>
```

pojo class

```
package com.Beans;

public class Employee {
public int id;
public String F_Name;
public String L_Name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getF_Name() {
    return F_Name;
}

public void setF_Name(String f_Name) {
    F_Name = f_Name;
}

public String getL_Name() {
    return L_Name;
}

public void setL_Name(String l_Name) {
    L_Name = l_Name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", F_Name=" + F_Name + ", L_Name=" + L_Name + ", getClass()=" + getClass()
            + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode() + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
}}
```

This is my data insertion code

```
 package com.Beans;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.Transaction;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
 public class Client {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration cfg= new Configuration(); 
    cfg.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Employee First Name:");
    String fname = sc.nextLine();
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Employee Last Name:");
    String lname = sc1.nextLine();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setF_Name(fname);
    e.setL_Name(lname);
    session.persist(e);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();        
} }
```

and this is my data retrieval class

```
 package com.Beans;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Scanner; 
  import org.hibernate.Query;
  import org.hibernate.Session;
  import org.hibernate.Transaction;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

  public class DataRetrieve {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Configuration cfg= new Configuration(); 
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the ID you want to see the record:");
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from employee where id =" + i);
    List list = query.list();
    Employee emp = new Employee();
        int j = emp.getId();
        if (j == i) {
            System.out.println(emp.getId()+"");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no fields found");
        }       
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}}
```

Error I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate.hbm.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3411)

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [com.Beans.Employee] not found on com.Beans.Employee
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:182)
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:174)
```

Comment: field [com.Beans.Employee] not found on com.Beans.Employee

Comment: The error stack seems quite self-explanatory.  Is there a package namespace collision?

Comment: every class in the project is under the com.Beans package and has been specified in Client.java and DataRetriev.java clearly

Comment: all classes in the same package? so why even have packages? find out where you use that field, and what it should be

Comment: Can you please provide us the hibernate.hbm.xml file

Comment: Have provided hbm file @ZeusNet

Comment: Maybe hibernate can't find your id column in your pojo. It's lowercase in Java and uppercase in your config file

Comment: not helping same errors again @ZeusNet

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is update in `Employees` from `<id name="Id">`  to `<id name="id">`  , make `Employees` implement `Serializable` and add a default constructor.
Also what exactly does this serve`<many-to-one name="com.Beans.Employee"></many-to-one>` as this looks problematic.

Comment: i did changes but no use

Comment: Did you try removing this <many-to-one name="com.Beans.Employee"></many-to-one>

Answer (score 0):

First of all clear your code from some stuff and let your programming tool generate getters and setters methods. I think this error is because of your getters and setters. Your `toString` method is bad too. Delete `super.toString` from it. 
After that you'll get error from this line:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from employee where id =" + i);
```

It should be Query

```
query = session.createQuery("from Employee where id =" + i);
```

like your class name.

Comment: Enter the ID you want to see the record:2
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: employee is not mapped [from employee where id =2]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `DataRetrieve` class

```
 package com.Beans;
  import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

  public class DataRetrieve {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Configuration cfg= new Configuration(); 
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the ID you want to see the record:");
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee where id =" + i);
    List list = query.list();
    if(list.size() > 0){
        Employee emp = (Employee) list.get(0);//new Employee();
        int j = emp.getId();
        if (j == i) {
            System.out.println(emp.getId()+"");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no fields found");
        } 
    }else {
        System.out.println("no Record found");
    } 

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}}
```

Edit:

```
hibernate.hbm.xml
```

An edit in configuration also.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-mapping>  
 <class name="com.Beans.Employee" table="employee">  
<id name="Id">  
 <generator class="increment"></generator>  
</id>  

<property name="F_Name"></property>  
<property name="L_Name"></property>  
 <!-- <many-to-one name="com.Beans.Employee"></many-to-one> -->
</class>  

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Edit:

```
  hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Check it also

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->
    <!--Below are other values for hbm2ddl.auto validate: validate the schema, 
        makes no changes to the database. update: update the schema. create: creates 
        the schema, destroying previous data. create-drop: drop the schema at the 
        end of the session. -->
    <!--property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Following image have the `hierarchy of cfg` files

[image]

It will helpful for you.

Comment: INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: hibernate.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)

Comment: My hierarchy is exactly same as you have given @shivam

Comment: where is your config xml files inside src folder or others.This error is coming when your mapping file is not found to the configuration. you put your hibernate.hbm.xml in side the package so remove it from your package

Comment: it is outside of the package but in the src folder

Comment: can you provide me screenshot of hierarchy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162337/discussion-between-shivam-and-naseer-ahammed).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String F_Name;
public String L_Name;
```

these properties name should be like fName, lName,
change this and try after and in xml configuration, add "column" attribute

Answer (score 0):

Here is minor problem in your code. Correct following line in `DataRetrieve` class.

```
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

to

```
cfg.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Comment: my configuration file name is hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: but you mentioned your configuration file name as Hibernate.cfg.xml in Client class or also in file name. So please maintain consistency in naming while asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<many-to-one name="com.Beans.Employee"></many-to-one>
```

Hibernate is expecting a field named "com.Beans.Employee" here. Delete this line.

This is clearly stated in the error message:

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: **field [com.Beans.Employee] not found on com.Beans.Employee**